# Query number of records across all databases

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have multiple databases in my SQL Server. All databases are the same in structure but have different data. These databases are used to store sensor data so each sensor has it's own seperate DB in the SQL Server.

I want a query to Select the Database name and number of records in a specific table of each DB.

I tried with a cursor. I get error saying the name {query} is not a valid identifier. My Cursor is as follows:

```
Declare @dbname Varchar (50), @sql Varchar(1000)

Declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name LIKE 'EP505-%' -- All sensors of EP505

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @sql= 'SELECT Count(*) FROM [' + @dbname + '].dbo.TimeLine'
   EXEC  @sql
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

In the output I require the db name and the number of records for the `TimeLine` table.

What's the best way to achieve what I am trying.

Comment: Try `EXEC (@sql)` otherwise SQL Server will interpret your `@sql` contents as a stored procedure or user-defined function rather than a query string.

Comment: It works, How can I get @dbname in it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exec failed because the name not a valid identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11991987/exec-failed-because-the-name-not-a-valid-identifier)

Answer (score 2):

Use parentheses when executing a SQL query string like so:
`EXEC (@sql)`. Without parentheses, SQL Server will interpret `@sql` as a stored procedure or user-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

your attempt looks quite good so far.

Please try adding a fetch next below the exec-line and try putting the @SQL variable after the exec brackets. That worked in my SQL Server environment.

hope this helps

br
Patrik

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sp_executeSQL](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/build-sql-server-dynamic-sql-query-example.aspx) to execute your dynamic query instead of exec statement which will help you to solve your issue

Here is the modified version

```
Declare @dbname Varchar (50), @sql nVarchar(1000)

Declare db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT name
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
WHERE name LIKE 'kodyaz' -- All sensors of EP505

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SET @sql= N'SELECT Count(*) FROM [' + @dbname + '].dbo.Kontaktpersonen'
   exec sp_executesql @sql
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname
END
CLOSE db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

I change **@sql** data type to **nvarchar()** and use

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```